# Mapzen / Tangram topojson building data alternatives

Tags: vector-tiles, mapzen, building-heights

I'm using Vizicities to visualise 3d building data on a map. Vizicities uses Mapzen vector tiles:

http://tile.mapzen.com/mapzen/vector/v1/buildings/{z}/{x}/{y}.topojson?api_key=[key]

With Mapzen closing, I've been looking for alternatives, like Tangram, but it seems Tangram is also relying on Mapzen data.

Is there any alternative that provides vector tile building data in a topojson format that might replace Mapzen?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any alternative.

From my viewpoint, you can build your own webservice using Mapzen code.
Mapzen company had to shutdown but their code "to make the job" is available.

See https://github.com/tilezen/vector-datasource/wiki/Mapzen-Vector-Tile-Service

It's a solution far from perfect (create your own infrastructure) but at least, it lets you an option to deal with the issue.

Edit: you will be able to postpone the issue due to this announcement https://mapzen.com/blog/long-term-support-mapzen-maps/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Nextzen](https://www.nextzen.org/). They are providing long term support for Mapzen maps, vector and terrain tiles. I've been using them in some of my maps and it works just fine. The only thing you need to change is the source in your `scene.yaml` file. Mine read something like this:

`sources:
  mapzen:
    type: MVT
    url: https://{s}.tile.nextzen.org/tilezen/vector/v1/512/all/{z}/{x}/{y}.mvt
    url_subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
    url_params:
      api_key: 'YOUR_NEXTZEN_API_KEY_HERE'
    tile_size: 512
    max_zoom: 16`